# Why does including an arbitrary STL header resolves these compilation errors?

Tags: c++, stl

I have this global function in my program:

```
static bool IsValidType(const CString& cType)
{
    for (auto pType : {"bmp","jpg","jpeg","gif","tif","tiff","png"})
        if (cType == CString(pType))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

And it gives me the following compilation errors:

```
error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'initializer-list'
error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'initializer-list'
error C2065: 'pType' : undeclared identifier
```

I can resolve it by including an arbitrary STL header before the function body, for example:

```
#include <string>
static bool IsValidType(const CString& cType)
{
    ...
}
```

But of course, I don't think that this is the correct way to do it.

Why does including an arbitrary STL header resolve this problem, and how I should go about resolving it correctly?

Comment: Should probably add that I am using MFC here (hence the `CString`)...

Comment: I guess you need to include `<iterator>` which gets included in STL header files

Comment: Oh, or just include `<initializer_list>`.

Comment: The correct header to include is `<initializer_list>`, which happens to also be included by many other standard headers.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thank you. I assumed that the `for (auto pType : {...})` notation was part of the natural C++ syntax. From all the comments and answers here, I understand that it is not...?

Comment: @goodvibration - It is part of the C++ syntax, however the part after the `:` might need some header included.

Comment: It's a specific call-out in the C++ Standard that using a `std::initializer_list` (the `{...}` part here), you *must* include the header, even if you never explicitly named `std::initializer_list`. See the last sentence of [\[dcl.init.list\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#2).

Answer (score 9):

Since you are using [initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) you should include `initializer_list`.

```
#include <initializer_list>
```

Including `string` resolve the error as `string` probably includes `initializer_list`, but that kind of indirect include is not the recommended way.

Answer (score 4):

> Can you please explain to me why including an arbitrary STL header resolves this problem,

Because many standard headers include other ones in their implementation.

> and how I should go about resolving it correctly?

Include the headers that are dedicated to contain these missing functions/types.
In your case that is the `<iterator>`, `<initializer_list>` header according to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin).

Comment: Thank you. I assumed that the `for (auto pType : {...})` notation was part of the natural C++ syntax. From your answer, I understand that it is not...?

Comment: @goodvibration - It is part of natural C++ syntax. But the container in use must support the protocol. The object created by `{...}` is a `std::initializer_list`, that one doesn't usually iterate like you did. So the protocol related stuff aren't pulled in without the header.

Comment: @goodvibration `for (auto x : y)` is part of the "natural" syntax as you say; but using `y` as an initializer_list requires inclusion of the initializer_list header

Answer (score 1):

Not *an arbitrary* STL header.

If you look at the definitions of `std::begin` and `std::end` in the standard, it says: (in [iterator.container]/p1):

> 1 In addition to being available via inclusion of the `<iterator>` header, the function templates in 27.8 are available when any of the following headers are included: `<array>`, `<deque>`, `<forward_list>`, `<list>`,`<map>`, `<regex>`, `<set>`, `<string>`, `<unordered_map>`, `<unordered_set>`, and `<vector>`.

Amusingly enough, `<string_view>` is not on that list.

- There's an [existing defect report](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#3009) report about that.
- libc++, at least, *does* define `std::begin` and `std::end` if you include `<string_view>`.

Comment: 3009 is `size/empty/data`. `begin/end` is 2812, which is in C++17 (also, 2812 just repeats in [iterator.range] what [string.view.synop] already said, so it's not even strictly necessary).

Comment: Also, OP uses `initializer_list`, which has its own `begin/end` in [support.initlist.range], which isn't affected by this wording.